# How do I make a FloatLayout Scrollablle using the ScrollView function in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to figure out how i can scroll through a float layout which has widgets in various places, however when I add the floatlayout to the scrollview it doesn't scroll all the way. However, when I do this with a gridlayout, it seems to be perfectly scrollable. I would appreciate it if anybody helped me with this.

Here is my code:

KIVY

````
WindowManager:
    ProfileWindow:


<ProfileWindow>:
    name: 'Profile'

    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgba: .94,1,.9, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: 1.4
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y': .01}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: None
            size: root.width, root.height        

            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: 100
                width: 100

                text: 'test 1'

                pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0.2}
                colour: (1, 0, 0, 1)

            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: 100
                width: 100

                text: 'test 2'

                pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':-0.4}
                colour: (1, 0, 0, 1)

            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: 100
                width: 100

                text: 'test 3'

                pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':-1.0}
                colour: (1, 0, 0, 1)

            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: 100
                width: 100

                text: 'test 4'

                pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':-1.4}
                colour: (1, 0, 0, 1)```
````

PYTHON file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import csv
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.effects.kinetic import KineticEffect
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

class ProfileWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


Build_LearnAB = Builder.load_file('sfl.kv')

class LearnScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Build_LearnAB

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LearnScrollViewApp().run()
```

Comment: Maybe put grid/box(need few more works) layout in scrollview, and put floating layout inside? basically nesting it

Comment: yeah i tried nesting the FloatLayout in a Gridlayout but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some strange things in that code. First, using `size_hint` values greater than `1` (as you do for your `ScrollView`) sets the size of the `ScrollView` greater than its container. That means that you will not be able to see the entire `ScrollView`.

Similarly, you are setting `pos_hint` values to numbers less than `0`. That positions the `Buttons` outside of the `FloatLayout`, so they will not be visible.

I suggest eliminating the line:

```
size_hint_y: 1.4
```

from the `ScrollView` and just use the default value of `1`.

Then, set the height of the `FloatLayout` to something larger then the height of the `ScrollView`. The `ScrollView` will not scroll if its child is not larger than itself. For example, set the height of the `FloatLayout` to twice the height of the `ScrollView`:

```
size: root.width, root.height*2
```

Then, use `pos_hint` to place the `Buttons` in the `FloatLayout`, but keep the values between `0` and less than `1`, to place the `Buttons` within the `FloatLayout`.

Here is a modified version of your `kv` that makes these changes:

```
WindowManager:
    ProfileWindow:


<ProfileWindow>:
    name: 'Profile'

    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgba: .94,1,.9, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        # size_hint_y: 1.4
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y': .01}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: None
            size: root.width, root.height*2

            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: 100
                width: 100

                text: 'test 1'

                pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0.75}
                colour: (1, 0, 0, 1)

            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: 100
                width: 100

                text: 'test 2'

                pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0.5}
                colour: (1, 0, 0, 1)

            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: 100
                width: 100

                text: 'test 3'

                pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0.25}
                colour: (1, 0, 0, 1)

            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: 100
                width: 100

                text: 'test 4'

                pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0}
                colour: (1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot that works perfectly. Sorry about the rookie mistakes, i'm pretty new to kivy :)